# windows batch move files with wildcard behaves oddly

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

hi I have folder with images and when I run "move C:\test\from\007* C:\test\to\"
files beginning with 009 are copied as well:

C:\test\from>move C:\test\from\007*.jpg C:\test\to\

C:\test\from\007014_1112017.JPG

C:\test\from\009408_1112017_12.JPG

C:\test\from\009086_1112017_5.JPG

C:\test\from\009437_1112017_4.JPG

C:\test\from\009429_1112017_5.JPG

C:\test\from\009120_1112017_4.JPG

C:\test\from\009408_1112017_2.JPG

```
     7 file(s) moved.
```

how so?

Comment: I cannot replicate your output.  It only moves the **007** file when I test your exact folder structure and file names with the same command.

Comment: @Squashman as Magoo said dir /x shows file long name is "009429_1112017_5.JPG" but short "007971~1.JPG"

Comment: Pretty sure you are not showing us the actual file names.  All things being equal the short file names should be the same on all computers.  I tested your file names on Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 2008 Server and Windows 2012 server.  On all the systems not a singe one of your 009 files shows as a 007 first.  All 7 files show as the same short file name on all the systems.

Answer (score 1):

By default, files have a "long name" and a "short name".

Your `move` will move files that match your mask with *either* name.

You can display the shortnames for your files with `dir /x`

Answer (score 0):

Your work around is to use FINDSTR to match the actual output from the dir command.  The output from the dir command will always output the actual file name and not the short file name.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /a-d 007*.jpg^|findstr /r /c:"^007.*\.jpg"') do move "%%G" "C:\test\to\"
```

Comment: Personally, I'd favour `findstr /i /b /L /c:"007"` in this case (case-**i**nsensitive, **b**egins **L**iterally with **c**onstant string - but no doubt it's instance-dependent